# How to run Multiple [TestMethod] in order?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

i am asking how to run multiple test method in order that they are in same file.

For example i have this Unit Test File name

```
public class UniTest1
{
[TestMethod]
public void Login()

[TestMethod]
public void Logout()

[TestMethod]
public void SignIn()

[TestMethod]
public void ForgetPassword()

}
```

I want them in this order:

Login()

Logout()

ForgetPassword()

SignIn()

Just to clarify i want this order to check if this email already exist or not

Comment: You can set up an [ordered test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx)

Comment: Could you tell us more about this question? Why do you want them to be run in that specific order? Are you really trying to do one test (that checks login, logout, sign in and password reset), and not 4 tests? What is your *intention*?

Comment: While you can set up an ordered test, you should consider whether it's really good to have interdependent test cases.  This suggests that your tests are depending on things they shouldn't depend on, which may cause trouble down the line.

Comment: i wonder why i dont have order test option in my vs studtio 2017

Comment: Ideally the order of tests should not matter.  They really should be independent.  It's more likely that you should create one test that does everything in order for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your test cases to contain the code for the setup, action and assertions for that particular case, you do not need to run them in any particular order. A good advice would be to aim to not have any dependencies between the test cases, for instance, you should need to depend upon a "Login" test to have run prior to "LogOut". Instead the setup of the test code in the "LogOut" case would initiate the logged in session and set the stage for the "LogOut" action to happen.

If you find that multiple test cases share common setup code and teardown code, you could use the TestInitialize and TestCleanup properties on some methods, as such:

```
namespace UserInteractionTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UserAuthenticationTestt
    {

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestSetup()
        {
            /* Put your common initialization code here */
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void AnAuthorizedUserCanLogin()
        {
            /* put your setup, action and assertion here
             from your system under test
            */
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void ALoggedInUserCanLogOut()
        {
            /* put your setup, action and assertion here
             from your system under test
            */
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void TestCleanup()
        {
            /* Put your common teardown code here.. */
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think TestInitialize is not the solution in this case. He'll need a special init for every test.

Comment: If he needs a special init for each case, he should do the initialization in each test case, as I stated in my example. That is the Setup part of the test case code.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up one big Test with multiple steps but not four dedicated tests.

Here an example:

```
public class UniTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void LoginSuccess()
    {
        // Try to Log in
        o.Login("user", "pw");
        Assert.AreEqual(true, o.ImLoggedIn);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void LoginWrongPw()
    {
        // Try to Log in
        o.Login("user", "wrongpw");
        Assert.AreEqual(false, o.ImLoggedIn);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void LogOutSuccess()
    {
        // Login
        o.Login("user", "pw");
        // Check if steup is completed
        Assert.AreEqual(true, o.ImLoggedIn);

        bool ok = o.LogOut();
        Assert.AreEqual(true, ok);
    }

    [TestMethod, ExpectedException(NotLoggedInException)]
    public void LogOutNoLogout()
    {
        // Try to Log in
        Assert.AreEqual(false, o.ImLoggedIn);
        bool ok = o.LogOut();
    }
}
```

As you can see every test is independend from the others.

If you need a logout-test you have to setup the environment for it and not "hope" that other tests to so.